# TemplateBinding not passing into VisualBrush created in ControlTemplate.Resources

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I apologize in advance since I'm sure this has been posted before, I just can't seem to figure out how to phrase it correctly to find the answer.

I'm trying to create a style template for a CueTextBox (so when it's empty, it displays the tooltip in a lightened color) but it won't seem to pass the {TemplateBinding Property=ToolTip} to the Content of the label... If I just replace it with text, it works fine, but I can't get it to bind to the Textbox's Tooltip.

Here's the code

```
<Style x:Key="CueTextBox" TargetType="TextBox" xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#1e1e1e" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#434346" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                <Border x:Name="Bd" 
                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" 
                    CornerRadius="0">
                    <ScrollViewer VerticalAlignment="Center" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"  x:Name="PART_ContentHost"/>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Resources>
                    <VisualBrush x:Key="CueBannerBrush" AlignmentX="Left" AlignmentY="Center" Stretch="None">
                        <VisualBrush.Visual>
                            <Label Padding="5,0" Content="{TemplateBinding Property=ToolTip}" Foreground="#888888" />
                        </VisualBrush.Visual>
                    </VisualBrush>
                </ControlTemplate.Resources>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true" />
                            <Condition Property="Text" Value="{x:Null}" />
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource CueBannerBrush}"/>
                    </MultiTrigger>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true" />
                            <Condition Property="Text" Value="{x:Static sys:String.Empty}" />
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource CueBannerBrush}"/>
                    </MultiTrigger>
                    <Trigger Property="Text" Value="{x:Static sys:String.Empty}">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource CueBannerBrush}" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="Text" Value="{x:Null}">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource CueBannerBrush}" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#1e1e1e" />
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#007acc" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Usage:

```
<TextBox ToolTip="First Name" Style="{StaticResource CueTextBox}" />
```

Answer (score 2):

`{TemplateBinding Property}` is lightweight and fast, but very limited. In complex scenarios, use `{Binding PropertyPath, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}` or `{Binding PropertyPath, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ControlType}}}`.

You can set `PresentationTraceSource.TraceLevel=High` on bindings to see detailed evaluation log.

By the way, I don't understand why you use brushes for this... Why not just put a `TextBlock` into template and toggle its visibility?

Comment: I had the exact same issue. I also tried the two alternative bindings you've suggested, but none of them work. It is as though there's just no context inside <ControlTemplate.Resources> and <ControlTemplate.Triggers> (binding inside ControlTemplate.Triggers does not work either).
I ended up using a TextBlock as you've suggested, and that worked.